# How to search for a file by a hash value with bash script (terminal)?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I am writing a script for Mac OS X Lion 10.7 and I would like to know how I can search for files based on their SHA1 hashes. I would like to search the whole file system for the file(s) I will be looking for.

For example the SHA1 value `0d882ff2d5edd7d045c1b57320d2e046793868f8` corresponds to the file `MacOSXUpdCombo10.7.2.dmg` How can I search the hard drive for the file with its SHA1 value without needing to compare the file?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the **`find`** command:

```
find / -type f -exec sha1sum {} \; | grep 0d882ff2d5edd7d045c1b57320d2e046793868f8
```

However, since you're running this on all files, it may be extremely slow — try **limiting the search directory** by replacing `/` with the path to a specific directory you want to search.

Comment: You'll need to prefix that with `sudo` if you want the find to reach in to areas of the file system normally off limits to regular users.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to try using xargs depending on how many files you will be searching through.

```
find / -type f |
    xargs -I {} openssl sha1 {} | 
    grep 0d882ff2d5edd7d045c1b57320d2e046793868f8
```

Comment: `openssl` will still be called once per file thanks to the `-I` option of `xargs`, so there won't be any gain.

Comment: My apologies, you are correct I have edited my original statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few lines of command which may help find a file from its SHA1 digest. Let's say the file we are hunting is `MacOSXUpdCombo10.7.2.dmg`.

```
# store the size of the searched file
size=`/bin/ls -l MacOSXUpdCombo10.7.2.dmg | awk '{print $5}'`
# store the digest of the serached file
sha1=`/usr/bin/openssl sha1 MacOSXUpdCombo10.7.2.dmg | awk '{print $2}'`
/usr/bin/sudo find / -type f -size ${size} -exec /usr/bin/openssl sha1 {} \; |
    grep ${sha1}
```

This `find` will run on plain files and not directories, socket or special files. It will also only run on file of the right **size** thus
avoiding to make a digest of the Kernel or your iTunes library and on a flock of tiny temporary files.

If you are sure that the file name is including the right extension,
this find might be accelareted further with the following
argument list:

```
/usr/bin/sudo find / -type f -name "*.dmg" -size ${size} -exec /usr/bin/openssl sha1 {} \; |
    grep ${sha1}
```